# Despliegue EAR fallido con WebLogic 12.2.1.3.0

Tags: weblogic

<02-oct-2018 16H13' CEST>    
<02-oct-2018 16H13' CEST>    (SpringClassPreprocessor.java:26)
        at weblogic.spring.monitoring.instrumentation.SpringInstrumentationUtils.addSpringInstrumentor(SpringInstrumentationUtils.java:87)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>

Answer (score 0):

<02-oct-2018 16H13' CEST>    
<02-oct-2018 16H13' CEST>    (SpringClassPreprocessor.java:26)
        at weblogic.spring.monitoring.instrumentation.SpringInstrumentationUtils.addSpringInstrumentor(SpringInstrumentationUtils.java:87)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>